# Shall I use an article before the word "soul”?

Tags: articles, nouns

"soul" is not a countable noun, but I have saw some using for this word?

Comment: It has multiple meanings, some of which involve countable usage and some of which are uncountable.

Comment: 'Soul' surely is a countable noun for Christians, who believe that every person has one, that it is immortal, and that it persists after death. Also can be used metaphorically and countably, e.g. _The Soul of a New Machine_ (a book about the design of a new computer).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misconception.

Comment: You should add an example sentence and show us a context you'd like to use the word in.

Answer (score 2):

"Soul", in the sense if the "spiritual aspect of a person that survives death" is usually a countable noun.

> Three souls ascended to heaven.

In figurative uses it also usually countable:

> It was a place without a soul.

The genre of music is non-countable, "Soul was popular in Northern England"

Don't confuse with the adjective "sole", or the noun "sole" (meaning the bottom of the foot or shoe, though this is also countable)